# Unable to pass on or retrieve data to another class

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, popover

Trying to create a custom drop-down and facing issues in passing on data and retrieving the user selection from the custom drop-down. The solution however works when I use `static var`.

In the below code, I have a viewController class from where I am programmatically calling a `popOver`.

```
let countryDropDown = customDropdown()

    @IBAction func btMultiCountry(_ sender: Any) {
        ViewController.countryDropDown.removeAll() //fuction to clear the array before load
        for c in g.country{ //Array from which all items are loaded on the custom dropdown
            countryDropDown.addItems(labelText: c.countryName!, toggleState: 1) //passing the values in the add function to update the Array
        }
        countryDropDown.showDropdown(btMultiCountry) //programatically calling the function to display popover that has the collection view with the countries as items. 
    }
```

```
class customDropdown: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cvDropDown: NSCollectionView!
    
var pop = NSPopover() // if I put static var, the popover closes with the OK button as required, however, without static the OK button doest do anything
    var dropDownLabelText = [String]() //if I put static var, the values are shown on the collection view without any issue. Without static the array is blank that was load from additems function
    var dropDownToggle = [Int]() // same as above
    var selectedItemsIndex: [Int] {
        var a = [Int]()
        for (i,t) in dropDownToggle.enumerated() {
            if t == 1 {
                a.append(i)
                print(a)
            }
        }
        return a
    }

    func showDropdown(_ sender: NSButton){
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil)
        let VC = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "dropDownForm") as? customDropdown
        pop.contentViewController = VC
        pop.behavior = NSPopover.Behavior.transient
        pop.show(relativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        print(pop)
    }
    
    @IBAction func btOK(_ sender: Any) { //this function does not close the popover if there is not static mention above
        pop.close()
    }
```

I tried putting `static` when declaring the variables and it worked. I do not want `static` and want to create different instances of the class that gives me `selectedItemsIndex`

For eg:

```
let countryDropDown = customDropdown()
let personDropDown = customDropdown()
```

I should be able to get a different values for `countryDropDown.selectedItemsIndex` and `personDropDown.selectedItemsIndex`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is a "drop down" a popover?

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Why don't you load a view controller from the storyboard and present it as popover? It now looks like you create a view controller that loads another view controller and creates a popover. I think you're overcomplicating things. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your response Willeke! I am trying to create a custom dropdown using popover that is shown when the user clicks on a button. There is a collection view and a button to update the array with the user's selection of the collection view items on the popover. Once the component is ready, I want to use two buttons on the main view with different arrays loaded in the dropdown giving me different selected values that can be accessed by below   let countryDropDown = customDropdown()
    let personDropDown = customDropdown()

Comment: Which controller controls the collection view, `countryDropDown` or `dropDownForm`?

Comment: Thank you Willeke for trying to help me. You were right, as I am not an expert programmer, I complicated things. Finally was able to resolve the issue by creating and returning the view controller. After that I was able to access all the variables.     class func createDropdown() -> customDropDown{
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("customDropdown"), bundle: nil)
        let VC = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "DropDown") as! customDropDown
        VC.pop.contentViewController = VC
        return VC
    }